# Detect encoding in Python3 when BOM is present

Tags: python-3.x

For starters, I know that you can't always detect encoding, that's not the object of the question. Can Python detect the encoding when opening a file, **when there's a BOM giving the encoding** ?

I have a collection of files. Some are in UTF-16 (so they have a BOM saying so) and some are in latin 1. Let's ignore the edge case of latin-1 files that for some reason would start with the exact same characters as the UTF-16 BOM. I want, when opening the file, to look for a BOM. If there is one, automatically open the file using the encoding associated with the BOM. If there isn't a BOM, open with latin 1.

Here is my workaround :

```
with open(filename,mode="rb") as f:
    text=f.readlines()
    text=b''.join(text)
    if text[:2]==(b'\xff\xfe'):
        text=text.decode("utf-16")
    else:
        text=text.decode("iso-8859-1")
```

Is there some kind of module that replaces "open" to do that, with all encodings that have a BOM ?